# How to add a certificate url in maven cli

Tags: java, maven, ssl-certificate

I'm building a Java maven project. While running maven install command, I'm getting the following error

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried downloading the certificates from the private artifactory and added it in the keystore. Now if I do maven command with flag,

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts
```

maven build is working fine. I want to know if is it possible to directly pass the URL of my artifactory certificate and make maven use it.

Comment: I doubt it. But if it's now working for you, why would you want to?

Comment: @g00se    This is part of implementing whitesource security scan and I need to implement it in this way by only modifying the maven command

Comment: @Sebin You can also add the certificate to the Java installation. It might be worthwhile to share a standard JDK with company certificates for all your developers.

Answer (score 1):

What you did -setting the default truststore to a Java keystore file that includes the custom certificate- is what the Maven documentation says to do in this scenario: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html

You may need to use a copy of the default truststore (usually found at JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts) so it contains all the default certificates to also connect to other sites signed by well-known Certificate Authorities.